# git push says everything up to date but it isn't

Tags: git, github, push

Hi I'm learning git thesedays and there's some problem with me. Can anyone read this? I write all the words.

$ git add hi.cc

$ git commit -m "hello stackoverflow"
[HEAD 분리됨 a0121cb] hello stackoverflow     // sorry it's korean. I think it means git head detached from a0121cb

1 file changed, 47 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 temp/hi.cc

$ git push origin master

Username for 'https://github.com':

Password for 'https://myname@github.com':

Everything up-to-date

However sadly when I check my github, nothing was changed. I searched many questions similar to mine, but I couldn't fix it.

This is my git log :
$ git log

commit a0121cb2f62b82702041f00f628d1fb165751d9f

Author: J.Victor

Date:   Tue Jul 12 13:22:24 2016 +0900

```
hello stackoverflow
```

Comment: Provide your git config file .git/config and full git status output

Answer (score 4):

If it's in detached HEAD state, use `git push origin HEAD:master`. But please make sure HEAD is ahead of your local master and is not diverged from your local master. One possible commit history is like

```
A-B-C-D->HEAD
*master* points to C
```

Or a better and more generic solution,

```
git branch myhead
git checkout master
git rebase myhead
git push origin master
```

Comment: There are many similar questions out there with a host of responses. This answer is the only one I found that solved my problem. I am so grateful I stumbled on this answer and wish I could upvote more than once. Why does this answer not have more upvotes?!